# plugin processing

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

Plugin processing: The plugin will be disabled because it crashed QGIS during last startup. Please report an issue and re-enable the plugin when the problem has been solved.
I have this problem in my QGIS , how do I can solve it?

Comment: I experience this issue when opening two instances of QGIS simultaneously. After a restart the processing plugin works properly again.

Comment: In my case I solved it by deleting qgis settings folder.

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have the processing plugin under C:\users\username.qgis2\python\plugins? If yes, delete it and try again.

Processing is now a core feature, stored in the programs subfolder.